# orderBy múltiple usando pyspark python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Hacer orderBy para 3 columnas, de la siguiente forma:

`col1` Ascendente
`col2` Ascendente
`col3` Descendente

Intente de la siguiente forma, pero lo deja todo ascendente:

```
 training=training.orderBy(['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Yo quiere que la `col3` sea descendente

Comment: ¿Puedes ampliar un poco la pregunta para darte contexto y conseguir una respuesta que sea útil? `orderBy` es una instrucción de `SparkSQL` y no conocemos cómo la estás usando. Por otro lado, te sobraría la etiqueta [tag:pandas], ¿no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la [documentación](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy):

> **orderBy(*cols, **kwargs)** Returns a new DataFrame sorted by the
>   specified column(s).
>
> Parameters:
>
> **cols** – list of Column or column names to sort by.
>
> **ascending** – boolean or list of boolean (default True). Sort ascending
>   vs. descending. Specify list for multiple sort orders. If a list is
>   specified, length of the list must equal length of the cols.

Tienes el parámetro `ascending` para establecer el orden, por ejemplo si quieres todas las columnas en orden ascendente salvo la tercera, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
training=training.orderBy(['col1','col2','col3'], ascending=[1, 1, 0])
```

Nota: la lista `ascending` es de booleanos, pero te indique el ejemplo tal como está expresado en la documentación que te pasé, usando valores 1 y 0. Entiendo que sería igual hacer `ascending=[True, True, False]`. No olvides que cuando configuras este parámetro la lista debe tener la misma cantidad de elementos del parámetro `cols`.